# Flask serving Vue.js bundle file. Re-compile on change?

Tags: flask, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I'm using flask as my backend and Vue.js for my frontend. I created my VueJS project with vue-cli.

The way I have my project setup right now is that my backend is serving my static files. I, npm run build, and output the bundle files to my backend.

Everything works. It's just annoying to build every time.

I would like to re-compile my bundle every time I make changes to Vue. Is this possible? Modify my webpack?

Note: My project/flask is dockerized too.

Comment: Are you able to run `npm run dev`? It should watch files and build whenever the files are changed if it's defined in package.json.

Comment: @Nathan I could run `npm run dev` but I need to somehow point my backend to point at the non "bundle" file. I can't seem to find the entry point. There a `index.html` when i created my app with the `vue-cli` but there no JS.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1120 then I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-build-watch